# About closable operators

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

I was wondering, if the closure of two operators in a Hilbert Space with dense domain, both
have the same domain $D$, is equal to the composition of the closure of each operator, I mean
\begin{equation}
\overline{ac}(u)= \bar a \bar c (u) \quad  \forall \quad u\in D
\end{equation}
Maybe this questions is basic, but I haven't found the solution.

Comment: What happens if $a$ is the $0$ operator?

Comment: the 0 operator is closed, then both sides are equal to zero

Comment: And if the $0$ operator is defined an a dense domain, instead of everywhere?

Comment: the operator 0 with dense domain is not more closed?  I don't see why not.

Comment: Ok, I found that the answer its not haha

Comment: So, it's falso but however, do we have an inclusion at least?